# startActivityForResult(m_intent, CAMERA_REQUEST) Request Returning Zero while photo captured successfully from Camera

Tags: android, image-capture

```
Intent m_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyPhoto.jpg");
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            m_intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(m_intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Photo got clicked successfully but Resutl of Activity returns 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DeGM Narmadapuram, Here I am sharing full code for clicking image from Camera and show it to imageview.

```
try {
                val chooserIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                captureFile = createImageFile(this@TIDProcessActivity)

                if (captureFile != null) {

                    val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this@TIDProcessActivity,
                        "com.abcdemo.fileprovider",
                        captureFile
                    )

                    chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                }
                startActivityIntent.launch(chooserIntent)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: " + e.message)
            }
```

From this method you can capture picture and that picture has URI already created while clicking image so when you get result you can directly show image from this URI like below :

```
var startActivityIntent = registerForActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult>(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(captureFile.absolutePath)
        if (bitmap != null) {
            val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
            Glide.with(this).load(bitmap).into(binding.zeroTokenImagePath)
        }

    }
```